# Basic HTML Javascript program.. What is wrong with this?

Tags: javascript, html, validation

```html
        <!DOCTYPE html>
    
    <html>
    <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>circle area</title>
    <script>
    function start() { var button = document.getElementbyId("butto");
    button.addEventListener("click",area,false);}
    
    function area() {
    var input = document.getElementbyId( "radius" );
    var radius = parseFloat(input.value);
    var result = document.getElementbyId( "result" );
    result.innerHTML = "sphere volume is: "+spherevolume( radius );
    }
    function spherevolume( radius ) {
    return MATH.PI * MATH.pow(radius,2);}
    window.addEventListener( "load", start, false );
    </script></head>
    <body>
    <form action="#">
    <p><label>Radius:<input id="radius" type="number"></label>
    
    <input id="butto" type="button" value="click here"></p>
    </form>
    <p id="result"></p>
    </body>
    
    </html>
```

Please check this basic script to input radius from a form and print the radius of the circle.. I am unable to check why it is not working..
Also like W3C validator , is there someone for javascripts as well which can also comment on functionality of a code (I have tried [jslint](http://www.jslint.com) but it is unable to tell me anything about performance of code.)

Comment: what error is it throwing?

Comment: Where do you call the JS function inside html? Or you'd like to make it with listeners?

Comment: Just a typo in the post: `getElementbyId` (three times), or in your real code too?

Comment: Are you trying to print the radius of the circle (as your question indicates), or its volume (as your names indicate), or its area (as the formula would indicate)?

Comment: this is exactly what my code is.. I am studying from internet and WWW 5e(by deitel&deitel) and in its problem 9.6, it has been told to do like this.. Copy this code and run it in chrome.. In its console, it displays no error..

Comment: Why are you "unable to check why it is not working"? How did you try to check? Did you view the console? Did you debug? `jslint/jshint` is not supposed to tell you about performance--no one cares about performance. It might tell you about syntax errors, but to do that, you need to put the JS in a separate file.

Comment: I find it hard to believe there is no error in the console. When `start` runs (does it?), it should immediately choke on the misspelled function name `getElementbyId`.

Comment: believe me, there was no error in console.. I am using chrome 38.. And how to verify that it entered the console??

Comment: I did not say "verify that it entered the console", I said "verify that it entered the `start` routine". The way you do that is to use a **breakpoint**. If you don't know how to use breakpoints, then stop anything else you are doing and learn it now. Read a basic tutorial on devtools. You can hardly expect to ask a question on StackOverflow every time you make a typo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- `getElementById` should have a capital B
- `Math` should not be all caps.

Once these are fixed, the code works (although it is calculating the area of a circle not the volume of a sphere). I suggest looking in your browser console from now on, because it most likely would have pointed you toward the place where the issue was.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>circle area</title>
    <script>
        function start() {
            var button = document.getElementById("butto");
            button.addEventListener("click",area,false);
        }

        function area() {
            var input = document.getElementById( "radius" );
            var radius = parseFloat(input.value);
            var result = document.getElementById( "result" );
            result.innerHTML = "sphere volume is: "+spherevolume( radius );
        }
        function spherevolume( radius ) {
            return Math.PI * Math.pow(radius,2);
        }
        window.addEventListener( "load", start, false );
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form action="#">
        <p>
            <label>Radius:<input id="radius" type="number"></label>
            <input id="butto" type="button" value="click here">
        </p>
    </form>
    <p id="result"></p>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

First, Your code has some spell errors at getting the id and using the math function that I have marked below:

```
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>circle area</title>
<script>
function start() {
var button = document.getElement*ById*("butto");
button.addEventListener("click",area);
}    
function area() {
var input = document.getElement*ById*( "radius" );
var radius = parseFloat(input.value);
var result = document.getElement*ById*( "result" );
result.innerHTML = "sphere volume is: "+ spherevolume( radius );
}
function spherevolume( radius ) {
return **Math.PI * Math.pow**(radius,2);
}
window.addEventListener( "load", start);
</script></head>
<body>
<form action="#">
<p><label>Radius:<input id="radius" type="number"></label>

<input id="butto" type="button" value="click here"></p>
</form>
<p id="result"></p>
</body>

</html>
```

If you have corrected those, it will be working. But it will log some error if the text box is empty. You can use 'if' condition to check the value.

Answer (score -1):

There is only 2 small error in your whole source code:

You have typed:

**getElementbyId** but it should be **getElementById**

Also

**MATH** should be **Math**

Comment: Case sensitivity is a good thing, heck even the English language is case sensitive :p

Comment: To OP: Why would you accept a later answer? JLRishe's was earlier. @GauravSaxena, I am not the downvoter, but for a question like this IMHO it would be more appropriate to leave a comment asking the OP to check his code for typos, or advising him how to use the console to find them himself.

Comment: If you want a case-insensitive language, you could try FORTRAN, COBOL, or BASIC.

Comment: okay... JLrishe's answer accepted... anyways, this queation is not so bad to be down-rated..